# Fit with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to fit a power curve into my data with the following gnuplot code.

```
f(x) = a*x**b;
fit f(x) 'data.txt' u 2:4 via a,b
plot 'data.txt' u 2:4 w l, f(x) w l
```

The estimate value of a and b seems to be good, however the plot is strange. 
I tried to set appropriate initial values for a and b but I have the same problem.

Here is my data file
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09032867895093746864

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure, that you uploaded the correct file? The fourth column contains always the same value (1.91088e-22). Would also be helpful to know what you mean with "strange". And did the fit converge?

Comment: Ah yes I made a mistake, I mean "u 1:2" and not "u 2:4". The fit converge but when I plot the result, the fit is not good even if the RSS seems to be good. I think it's a problem of starting value...I don't what value to take

Comment: The result I get from a fit using gnuplot version 5 is this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/M0toO.png. You won't get a better fit with the model you are using. Probably you must adapt your fitting function to reflect the curve shape.

Comment: But if I take the following intervall [0:0.0009], the power curve may be the best fitting function. However I still have the problem with the fitting I get with values of a and b given by the fit...